# Why do I get errors when I use the overloaded assignment operator, but I don't get using the compiler-supplied one?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, return-type, assignment-operator

I tried my best to only put the most important parts:

**header.h**

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "byte.h" /// doesn't matter what's in here
#pragma once

using int64 = int64_t;
using int32 = int32_t;

/// FORWARD-DECLARATIONS
class BigInt;

/// *** CLASS BIGINT ***

class BigInt
{
    std::vector<byte> vec;
    bool neg; /// true if negative

public:
    /// CONSTRUCTORS
    BigInt ();
    BigInt (const int64);

    /// OPERATORS
    /// ASSIGNMENT
    void operator = (const BigInt&);

    /// ARITHMETIC
    BigInt operator + (const BigInt&);
    BigInt operator - (const BigInt&);
};

/// DEFINITIONS
/// CONSTRUCTORS
BigInt::BigInt () : vec(1), neg(0) {}
BigInt::BigInt (const int64 x) : vec(x), neg(0) {}

/// OPERATORS
/// ASSIGNMENT
void BigInt::operator = (const BigInt &p)
{
    (*this).vec = p.vec;
    (*this).neg = p.neg;
}

/// ARITHMETIC
BigInt BigInt::operator + (const BigInt &p)
{
    BigInt a = *this;
    BigInt b = p;
    BigInt res;

    if (a.neg ^ b.neg)
    {
        if (a.neg)
            std::swap(a, b);
        b.neg = 0;
        /*return*/ res = a.BigInt::operator - (b); /// I get an error if I don't comment this out
        return res;
    }

    return res;
}

BigInt BigInt::operator - (const BigInt &p)
{
    BigInt a = *this;
    BigInt b = p;
    BigInt res;

    return res;
}
```

In `BigInt BigInt::operator + (const BigInt &p)` I get an error when I try to return `return res = a.BigInt::operator - (b);`, but not when I return it like this: `res = a.BigInt::operator - (b); return res;`. But this only happens when I overload the `=` operator, it doesn't happen with the compiler supplied one.

**ERROR:** *no viable conversion from returned value of type 'void' to function return type 'BigInt'* `return res = a.BigInt::operator - (b);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator=` returns `void`, which can't be returned in `return res = a.BigInt::operator - (b);`, as the error message said, `operator +` is supposed to return a `BigInt`.

You should declare `operator=` as returning `BigInt&` (as the one generated by compiler does).

```
BigInt& BigInt::operator = (const BigInt &p)
{
    (*this).vec = p.vec;
    (*this).neg = p.neg;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that modifying (*this) would be enough. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, you can also declare the assignment operator as `BigInt &operator = (const BigInt &) noexcept = default;` in the header and avoid having to define it in the file, or you are able to not include this operator at all (see [the rule of three-five-zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)). As of now, you cannot construct by copy, and there is no move operations. See also [C.20 in the C++ core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-zero).

Answer (score 2):

```
void BigInt::operator = (const BigInt &p)
```

I don't think that's right (the `void` return). The result of an assignment should be the value that's assigned, this is what allows you to do things like:

```
a = b = 7
```

or, more importantly in this case:

```
return res = ...
```

The `operator=` should probably return the `BigInt&` of the variable you put the value into, such as:

```
BigInt &BigInt::operator=(const BigInt &p) {
    this->vec = p.vec;
    this->neg = p.neg;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought that `res` for example will be stored at `this` pointer, so when I modify (*this), it modifies the left operand. But it works as you said, thank you!

Comment: @H-005: it *does* modify `*this` but that's only one of the two effects needed, the other is to return a value for the assignment expression. In other words `b = 7` will modify `*this` (which is `b`) to be seven. But, if the result of the expression `b = 7` is a void "type", you couldn't then do `a = b = 7`.